# Gradient descent inside the expectation-maximization (EM) algorithm

Tags: statistics, optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am feeling super uncertain about how much I can play around with the EM algorithm. Here is my question:

In the EM algorithm, during the M-step, one attempts to find a parameter value, $\theta$, that maximizes $Q$.

Sometimes the function of $Q$ with respect to that parameter value is continuous, differentiable and concave, but does not have a closed form solution for the stationary points and requires some form of numerical techniques, like gradient descent or Newton-Raphson method, to find the stationary points.

Am I correct to conclude that one does not break the convergences of the EM algorithm if you use these numerical methods to optimize $Q$ with respect to some parameter value $\theta$.

In fact, am I correct to conclude that one could use any optimization technique in the E step for all the parameters we wish to optimize for?

Comment: What’s the EM algorithm?

Comment: @bubba, the Expectation-Maximization algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use any optimization technique, including numerical, in the M (maximization) step.

In fact, you needn't even maximize; as long as the M step improves the objective function `Q`. The Generalized EM Algorithm, is described for example, in section 7 of ["The EM Algorithm As a Lower Bound Optimization Technique", by Rave Harpaz and Robert Haralick](https://academicworks.cuny.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1268&context=gc_cs_tr). I have substituted your notation for the paper's notation in the below quote from that section.

> In the M-step, the parameters $\theta$ were chosen as the value for which the
> lower bound of the objective `Q` was maximized. While this ensures the
> greatest increase in `Q` and subsequently the
> log-likelihood, it is possible to relax the requirement of
> maximization to one of simply increasing `Q`. This approach
> to simply increase and not necessarily maximize is known as the
> Generalized Expectation Maximization (GEM) algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer helpful answer and for including the paper.