# How is the "Maximization" Step done in the "EM" (Expectation Maximization) Algorithm?

Tags: probability, optimization, normal-distribution, machine-learning, affine-geometry

The Expectation-Maximization Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) is a well known optimization algorithm that is useful in situations when the function being optimized depends on some "unobservable information".

As an example, consider Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) Clustering - given some data points, we assume that the underlying data generating process for this data comes from some affine combination of Gaussian Distributions. We choose some discrete number of Gaussian Distributions - the problem now becomes to estimate the "mean and standard deviation" parameters for these distributions as well as estimating the "weight" of each of these Gaussian Distributions to the overall mixture. In practice, this estimation process is often  iteratively handled using the EM algorithm.

In this problem, we first write an expected likelihood of the Gaussian Mixture model - we then "maximize" this likelihood, and again update the expected likelihood. We repeat this process until some convergence criteria is met. This being said, I have the following question:

- **How exactly is the maximization step being performed?** On the Wikipedia page, it appears that the maximization step might have some analytical solution. However, a note is left indicating that "*Q(θ | θ(t)) being quadratic in form means that determining the maximizing values of θ is relatively straightforward*". Does this mean that even within the EM algorithm itself, another optimization algorithm such as Gradient Descent or BFGS is being used to perform the maximization step?
- A side note from my side - if the above point is true, i.e. the EM algorithm itself uses a gradient based optimization algorithm to perform the maximization step .... what is stopping us from using Gradient Descent on the original optimization problem? Is this just a matter of personal preference, i.e. for such optimization problems, it depends on my "mood" as to whether I use EM or Gradient Descent? **Or are there some optimization problems where algorithms like Gradient Descent fundamentally won't work and EM is thus required?**

Thank you!

Comment: Someone just upvoted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413654/gradient-descent-inside-the-expectation-maximization-em-algorithm/4413860#4413860 yesterday (perhaps you?). It addresses your first question.

Comment: @ Mark L Stone : Thank you! I just upvoted now!

Comment: @ Mark L Stone: This is something I have always struggled to understand: if I can use Gradient Descent during the "M-Step" ... why can't I just use Gradient Descent and completely avoid the EM algorithm all together?

Comment: Seeing that the EM algorithm is so popular.... I am assuming that for the EM algorithm ... there MUST be some specific advantages for specific optimization problems

Comment: You can try multiple algorithms and choose the one which works best for your problem (class).

Comment: @ Mark L. Stone: Thank you for your reply! This is precisely the point I am interested in understanding. In my very (very) limited knowledge of math, I understand that for some problems, a certain type of optimization algorithm can not be used. For example, the Loss Function in the Travelling Salesman Problem is defined over an Integer Domain - therefore, popular optimization algorithms like Gradient Descent can not be used (Evolutionary Algorithms can be used instead).

Comment: In other problems, there might sometimes optimization algorithms that are more favorable than other optimization algorithms. For example, in a Linear Programming problem, you could use the Genetic Algorithm if you insisted - but we know that the Simplex Method has strong theoretical guarantees for its performance in Linear Programming problems.

Comment: As another example : I am sure if we insisted, if we could use a Newton Method or standard Gradient Descent to optimize the Loss Functions in Neural Networks - but the time required to do this (i..e compute the full Hessian Matrix or the full Jacobian Matrix) would be so much, that it makes more sense to use Stochastic Gradient Descent. However, from a fundamental perspective, a variety of optimization algorithms could be used in this problem.

Comment: This brings me to the essence of my question. In optimization problems where the EM algorithm is being used - in any of these problems, could Gradient Descent have been used instead? And what are some "advantages" of the EM algorithm? Are there any situations in which we believe that the EM algorithm might have some inherent advantages over the Gradient Descent? I have heard the EM algorithm is particularly useful in problems where there is "missing information" (e.g. GMM Clustering) - I am not sure if this claim is true, and if it is true -why is it true? Do you  have any information on this?

Comment: thank you so much @ Mark L Stone!

Comment: @ Mark L Stone; I posted a question about this - can you please take a look at it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488493/why-should-i-use-the-em-algorithm thank you!